# Getting a bank rss feed into my mysql database with php?

Tags: php, mysql, rss

I need some help getting a bank rss feed into my database. I've tried a few things but I just can't seem to get it to work.

The rss feed is from http://www.bankofcanada.ca/stats/assets/rates_rss/noon/en_all.xml

```
<?php

//Find and grab needed libraries and files.
require_once('proxy_bypass.php');
require_once ('config.php');

$url = $BOCRSS; // Bank of Canada RSS.

$rss = @simplexml_load_string(get_file($url)); // Get the rss feed data.

if($rss) {
 foreach($rss->item as $entry) { //For each RSS item in the rss xml file.
    $cb = $entry->children('http://www.cbwiki.net/wiki/index.php/Specification_1.1');

    //var_dump($cb);        
    //die();

    $code = $entry[targetCurrency];
    $curr = $entry[value];
    //echo $curr .' '. $code . '<br/>'; //Can be deleted - prints out data.

    $dbc = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_password); //Connect to Shares.
    mysql_select_db($db_name, $dbc); //Select database.
    $qry = "INSERT INTO $db_table (currencycode,rate) VALUES ('$code', '$curr')"; //Creates the query.
    if (!$dbc){
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); // Echo this is the connection to the database can't be made.

}

if (mysql_query($qry, $dbc)) {
    echo "Database created"; // Echo this if the RSS feed in placed in the database.
}
else {
    echo "Error creating database: " . mysql_error(); //Otherwise say this.
}
mysql_close($dbc); // Close the database connection.
}

} else echo "Error with RSS feed"; //Echo error if RSS is unreachable.

?>
```

The two files I have included get me through my university's proxy server and the config holds my mysql database details and urls for the rss feed.

The var dump gives me this:

*object(SimpleXMLElement)#63 (1) { ["statistics"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#65 (2) { ["country"]=> string(2) "CA" ["exchangeRate"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#66 (5) { ["value"]=> string(6) "1.0029" ["baseCurrency"]=> string(3) "CAD" ["targetCurrency"]=> string(3) "USD" ["rateType"]=> string(24) "Bank of Canada noon rate" ["observationPeriod"]=> string(25) "2012-02-01T12:15:00-05:00" } } }*

Now I'm a beginner to PHP so it's probably all wrong. I'm trying to get the 'targetCurrency' and 'value' into my database but all I get is 50+ empty rows. It must mean that the database is being generated but nothing is going in.
If anyone can change the code to get it to work, I would be greatly appreciated as I've tried to get it to work but to no avail.

Comment: **warning** your code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you use $cb (your first child nodes of each item) instead $element?

```
$code = $cb['targetCurrency'];
$curr = $cb['value'];
```

Also, please use something like `mysql_real_escape_string($rss_field_value)` to escape values you put in your SQL queries, to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: I changed my old code to have "code = $cb['targetCurrency']; +
$curr = $cb['value'];". I then did a var dump to see what came out. It both returned NULL. and my empty row problems still persist. Thanks anyways, what you said will stay as it seems like a logical answer. Thanks.